# Normalization: Two coloumns in a single row require data from the same table

Tags: normalization

I have a table which has the following fields:

Assignedto and completedby

These fields reference the employee table.

I was just wondering if this is normalized or whether I have missed something.

Thanks

Comment: your post makes very little sense. please expand and clarify . 2 tables where one has the following field and then a third employee table ? makes no sense.

Comment: Can you include the schemas for the tables? Including some "create table" statements will remove alot of ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is fine (and appropriate) to have more than one column in a table be a Foreign Key into another table.   Your case is a good example of this...

There are lots of examples actually -  A Customer Table can have a mailing address and a Delivery address, which both point to an Address table..  A Contact Table could have a HomePhone, WorkPhone, Fax, and Mobile column that all point to a Telephone table (although there are other better ways of doing this one)

Comment: (+1) Edited the question to fit this answer -- and it is the correct and most likely answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'll refer to your second table as "Stuff" since I don't know what else to call it.

It's [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#.22Nothing_but_the_key.22) if the AssignedTo and CompletedBy fields are both foreign keys to the Employee table. If you really want to go nuts with the normalization, you can have a third table, StuffCompletion, that has an identity column and those two values, and replace those two values in your Stuff table with a foreign key to StuffCompletion. I think most people would consider this overkill, and the schema gods may rain destruction upon you.

Comment: lol sorry it was a bit vague but that is what i meant. I was thinking about the 'stuffcompletion' (completed work orders) table but im still thinking like a programmer knowing its going to be painful to code that way :)

Comment: Just given what you told me I wouldn't do that; separating those two fields into another table probably won't give you much gains, unless you have 3 employees working on tens of thousands of Stuffs.